# How to economically make limited use of worker processes in Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, celery

Currently, we have a custom cms product for schools that is built in django and deployed via heroku. I do a new deployment for each school system we add.  (I'd like to switch my system over to a multi-tenant one, but that will be a big project.) I recently added some functionality that works best asynchronously (an emailer & asynchronous cache-refreshes for db-intensive actions). I've written my background tasks as celery tasks and they work well. The problem is that to have a celery worker running 24-7 will cost me 34.50/month per app when in reality these tasks will only have a few minutes of non-idle time per day. This cost will make using heroku nearly unfeasible given the way I'm currently using it with a different instance for each client. Has someone dealt with this scenario and can recommend how to be able to have background processing on a regular basis (preferably with celery) without having to run a worker process 24-7.  The cache-refresher needs to run every few minutes but the emailer will rarely run (only when they send out an email to subscribers).

Comment: You can rewrite it as django [managemend command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) and call it via heroku schedule. I have tested this approach succesfully. But be sure that proces ends!! (heroku will bill it as dyno running time)

Comment: @danihp this is an interesting approach.  If you want to post this approach as an answer and elaborate a bit, maybe with a brief example (and I'm able to get it to work), I'd be happy to accept it as an answer at this point. Either way, though, thanks.

Comment: @andrewGorcester's answer is too close to mine comment to post comment as answer.  Thanks about offer! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need your workers to engage immediately, you can use [the scheduler add-on](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) to regularly clear your task queue.

If you need a faster response time, then look at the [Python wrapper for the Heroku API.](https://github.com/heroku/heroku.py)  With this you can use a variety of methods to detect when you need to run a worker, and dynamically spin one up, and spin it back down when it is unneeded.  This is a non-trivial engineering task.

Comment: Do you have any sense of how i could reconcile Celery tasks with the scheduler add-on?  I get the basic idea of the scheduler addon (you write a process and when the process exits it is done until the next scheduled execution) but it could be challenging to decouple the tasks from celery at this point.

Comment: I was imagining that you could, in your scheduled task, look at the celery queue and run any jobs that exist.  However, I've never done this so I don't know how hard it would be.  A simpler alternative would be to just spin up an actual worker dyno with scheduler, and have the worker dyno spin itself down after it's out of jobs.  That way you won't need any logic in your scheduler except to look and see if you don't have any worker dynos, and if you don't, spin one up.

Comment: This is a great idea.  As you note, its non-trivial... I may have to do something more rudimentary until I have time to either rewrite the system as multi-tenant (where a worker task or two won't be as significant of an expense in the big picture), or implement an intelligent approach like the one you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, an answer to this question in blog-post form came through my RSS feed the same day I posted.

http://heyman.info/2012/dec/6/heroku-multiple-processes-single-dyno-with-foreman/

In sum: setup your Procfile to run Foreman, which can split your dyno time between your multiple processes.   Haven't tried it yet, but seems like a legit approach for low-traffic or testing sites.